# Lambda function error in MVC Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, lambda

I have a strange error in my .cshtml file. I'm trying to use this examples http://mvc.ext.net/#/MessageBus_Basic/Simple/ found in the Ext.net official site.

When i use the lambda symbol with a listener, i have no problem and i can get my view.

```
@(Html.X().FormPanel()

                .Layout(LayoutType.Fit).Items(
                        Html.X().GridPanel().ID("ObservedGrid")
                        .Listeners( l => 
                            {
                               l.Render.Handler = "alert('hi');";

                            }) ))
```

However if i use the lambda symbol with a MessageBusDirectEvents like below:

```
@(Html.X().FormPanel()

                .Layout(LayoutType.Fit).Items(
                        Html.X().GridPanel().ID("ObservedGrid")
                        .MessageBusDirectEvents(de => {
                             var e = new MessageBusDirectEvent { Name = "Msg.Server", Action = "ServerBusEvent" };
                             e.ExtraParams.Add(new Parameter("message", "data", ParameterMode.Raw));
                             de.Add(e);
                }) ))
```

i got an error at design time from visual studio 2010 in this line `.MessageBusDirectEvents(de => {`: *Error    2   Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Ext.Net.MessageBusDirectEvent[]' because it is not a delegate type*.
Please notice that i have just did some copy paste from the given example in mvc.ext.net web site.

UPDATE:

the action in the controller is:

```
public ActionResult ServerBusEvent(string message)
        {
            this.GetCmp<Panel>("Panel2").Body.CreateChild(new DomObject
            {
                Html = message,
                Tag = HtmlTextWriterTag.P,
                CustomConfig =
                {
                    new ConfigItem("style", "color:green;", ParameterMode.Value)
                }
            });

            return this.Direct();
        }
```

Comment: What does the `MessageBusDirectEvents` method look like?

Comment: That's not the method I asked for... it's the method you're trying to call which isn't compiling which I'm asking about. What's the signature of `MessageBusDirectEvents`?

Comment: Looks to me like `MessageBusDirectEvents` takes a collection/array as a parameter, not a lamba?

Comment: @JonSkeet the only signature is MessageBusDirectEvents().

Comment: Then why are you trying to pass an argument to it? In fact, it looks like that's *not* the signature, given the error message - it looks like there's a first parameter of `Ext.Net.MessageBusDirectEvent[]`...

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry jon there is two signatures:
1-MessageBusDirectEvents(params MessageBusDirectEvents[] events)
2-MessageBusDirectEvents(Action <MessageBusDirectEvents> action)

Comment: @DavidG there is two signatures:
1-MessageBusDirectEvents(params MessageBusDirectEvents[] events)
2-MessageBusDirectEvents(Action <MessageBusDirectEvents> action)